# Variable scope in R

Tags: r, function, scope

I have a data.frame named factor_nonagg with 50 rows and 3 columns. I wrote a function category() with argument factors. I am making changes to factors in the function. When I pass the data.frame to this function, no changes are made in the data.frame. 
Can someone help me in making permanent changes to my data.frame?

```
n=50
category=function(factors){
for(i in 1:n){
if(factors[i,1]>=90) factors[i,1]<-2*.45
else if(factors[i,1]>=65) factors[i,1]<-1*.45
else factors[i,1]<-0

if(factors[i,2]>=.190) factors[i,2]<-2*.25
else if(factors[i,2]>=.140) factors[i,2]<-1*.25
else factors[i,2]<-0

if(factors[i,3]>=.03) factors[i,3]<-2*.30
else if(factors[i,3]>=.015) factors[i,3]<-1*.30
else factors[i,3]<-0
}}
category(factor_nonagg)
```

Comment: Several problems here, but the most important for your question is that you need to have `return(factors)` at the end of your function and if you want to use that value to overwrite your `factor_nonagg` object, you need to use `<-`: `factor_nonagg <- category(factor_nonagg)`.

Answer (score 1):

R does not easily support pass-by-reference type behavior with functions. When you make a change to a parameter value within a function, a copy of the object is made and the changes last only as long as the function call.

Typically you have your function return the changed value (`return(factor)`), and assign that new value to the original variable:

```
factor_nonagg <- category(factor_nonagg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through rows of dataframes is going to be painfully slow. This is a vectorized approach that is admittedly untested in the absence of data but does not throw an error with the other test data offered by dardisco:

```
category=function(factors){
factors[[1]] <- 0.45*(0:2)[ findInterval(factors[[1]], c(-Inf, 65, 90, Inf) )]
factors[[2]] <- 0.25*(0:2)[ findInterval(factors[[2]], c(-Inf, 0.140, 0.190, Inf) )]
factors[[3]] <- 0.30*(0:2)[ findInterval(factors[[3]], c(-Inf, 0.015, 0.03, Inf) )]
   return(factors) }
```

And, of course, as with all functional languages, factor_agg would not be modified except with an assignment command:

```
category(factor_agg)                # no effect
factor_agg <- category(factor_agg)  # replacement occurs.
```

`findInterval` is a very useful vector-oriented function that can either be used to return a grouping value or used, as in this example, as an index to select from a set of either character or numeric values

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an output object in your function that returns the changes you make to your df. This is achieved by adding

```
return(factors)
```

just before your last curly bracket in your function definition.

Comment: No need for (and indeed not in the spirit of R) to use `return`.

Comment: @Konrad True, functions do not necessarily need an explicit `return` statement, because the last evaluated expression is taken as the output otherwise. However,the for-loop in this code returns NULL and therefore the whole function returns NULL if the output is not specified.

Comment: Just use `factors` then – no need for `return(factors)`. Better yet, of course, would be to refactor the function so that no `for` is used.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wouldn't go saying that it "isn't in the spirit of R" to not use an explicit return statement.  It has been shown to be slightly faster to omit it but I prefer seeing the return statement. Code clarity is more important, in my opinion, than than unnoticeable speed boost.  And while most R users will understand what is going on it makes it easier for others to read the code as well.

Comment: @Dason It’s got nothing to do with performance. It’s simply misinterpreting what functions and values *are* in functional programming (and R is a functional language), and thus on par with writing `if (x == TRUE)` instead of `if (x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
    f1 = sample(seq(150), size=50, replace=TRUE),
    f2 = sample(seq(250) / 1000, size=50, replace=TRUE),
    f3 = sample(seq(50) / 1000, size=50, replace=TRUE)
    )
### vals1 = values
### mult1 = multiplier
fun1 <- function(x, vals1, mult1){
    if (x >= max(vals1)) return(mult1*2)
    if (x >= min(vals1) & x < max(vals1)) return(mult1)
    return(0)
    }
within(df1,
       f1 <- sapply(f1, fun1, vals1=c(90, 65), mult1=0.45),
       f2 <- sapply(f2, fun1, vals1=c(0.19, 0.14), mult1=0.25),
       f3 <- sapply(f3, fun1, vals1=c(0.03, 0.15), mult1=0.3)
       )
```

This avoids the `for` (although short loops are not necessarily a bad thing), saves on typing and allows it to be more easily generalized if you want to change the values or multiplier. I'm using `return` in `fun1` as it has multiple exit points.